# What is Stack Overflow for?

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow

I feel like most questions I ask on Stack Overflow are on topic. The topic of programming. Yet I still get referred to [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

What's the intended purpose of Stack Overflow?

> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free.

Then why do programming questions get referred elsewhere?

Comment: emphasis on `Q & A site` not "programming" perhaps.  "what is a good sort method" for instance is programming related but OT because there is no one set of "right" answers because it depends

Comment: Stack Overflow is a relic of its time. You can safely ignore it. I don't know why I'm here.

Comment: The rules are rough, to prevent craziness

Comment: @BoltClock What are you talking about? You *aren't* here. Neither am I. None of us are. Well; except Shog9. Poor, lonely, Shog9...

Comment: @Coffee - What are the lines?

Comment: @BoltClock - Somehow, your username is *very* apt here

Comment: @MatUtter They are pretty well drawn out in the [help/on-topic]

Comment: You're kinda taking that line out of context. `Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free.`  - sure , of course... but there's a pretty long spiel afterwards. Also, a nice Venn diagram somewhere - do you mind adding that in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

StackOverflow is for programming questions encountered at the keyboard.

Programmers SE is for programming questions encountered at the whiteboard.

Comment: Clever clever Will :P